# Unable to get destinationURL data in connectionDidFinishDownloading for ios5

Tags: xcode4, nsurlconnection, ios5

I'm trying to get a list of assests urls to download. I'm using NSURLConnection in order to get a JSON file that have this list of urls.
in

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten
```

I'm getting 122239 as total bytes written.
when

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
```

is called I'm trying to read the url data in order to extract the JSON file:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:destinationURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
```

data is always giving me a nil value also there is 122239 byte written in this file and the error print description is showing "No such file or directory"

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x4a1b90 {NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Applications/CD8E4838-D78D-41DE-8896-360B7FC02A1D/tmp/c1749157e1d4317f6158a8490e138e7e, NSUnderlyingError=0x4c5ae0 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've got the same problem and did some googleling. This seems to be a bug. Hopefully an iOS update will fix this.

Comment: Did you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com ? If you think this is a bug, and you have a small code sample to demonstrate, you increase the chances of this being fixed dramatically, in my experience.

Comment: Did you file a bugreport for this? I just ran into the exact same problem you had. Everything works perfectly, expect the file does't exist like in the destinationURL.

Comment: I submitted this as a bug to Apple. Apple confirmed this is a bug and marked confirmed it has been reported by at least one other person by marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: I wasted my full day on this.

Answer (score 10):

`NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate` only works for Newstand apps so far. Please file a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` instead. It won't show up in the docs, but it's actually there (use *Open Quickly* to find it **Cmd+Shift+O**).

There you could use following methods

1. `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`
2. `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`

Comment: iIf NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate methods present in you class, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate will not be called. Watch out!

Comment: This totally worked for me.  And jAckOdE's advice is crucial here too.

Comment: ...but should only be used for small(ish) files.

Answer (score 0):

iIf NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate methods present in you class, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate will not be called. Watch out! – jAckOdE  Thanks to a comment in Erik Aigner's answer below.

Basically... The NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate overrides NSURLConnectionDataDelegate.  Beware!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
– (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
```

Above method is used to receive the data which we get using post method.

```
– (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

This method , you can use to receive the error report in case of connection is not made to server.

```
– (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

The above method is used to process the data after connection has made successfully.