# Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, http-post, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to send an HTTP Post with the iOS application that I'm developing but the push never reaches the server although I do get a code 200 as response (from the urlconnection). I never get a response from the server nor does the server detect my posts (the server does detect posts coming from android)

I do use ARC but have set pd and urlConnection as strong.

This is my code for sending the request

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                    initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",dk.baseURL,@"daantest"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"text/xml"
   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

    NSString *sendString = @"<data><item>Item 1</item><item>Item 2</item></data>";

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [sendString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[sendString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    PushDelegate *pushd = [[PushDelegate alloc] init];
    pd = pushd;
    urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:pd];
    [urlConnection start];
```

this is my code for the delegate

```
#import "PushDelegate.h"

@implementation PushDelegate
@synthesize data;

-(id) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [data setLength:0];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten
{
    NSLog(@"didwriteData push");
}
- (void)connectionDidResumeDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidResumeDownloading push");
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL
{
    NSLog(@"didfinish push @push %@",data);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    NSLog(@"did send body");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [self.data setLength:0];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *resp= (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSLog(@"got response with status @push %d",[resp statusCode]);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d
{
    [self.data appendData:d];

    NSLog(@"recieved data @push %@", data);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"didfinishLoading%@",responseText);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error ", @"")
                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    NSLog(@"failed &push");
}

// Handle basic authentication challenge if needed
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"credentials requested");
    NSString *username = @"username";
    NSString *password = @"password";

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                             password:password
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

@end
```

The console always prints the following lines and the following lines only:

```
2013-04-01 20:35:04.341 ApprenticeXM[3423:907] did send body
2013-04-01 20:35:04.481 ApprenticeXM[3423:907] got response with status @push 200
2013-04-01 20:35:04.484 ApprenticeXM[3423:907] didfinish push @push <>
```

Answer (score 189, accepted):

The following code describes a simple example using `POST` method.(*How one can pass data by `POST` method*)

Here, I describe how one can use of POST method.

**1.** Set post string with actual username and password.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Password=%@",@"username",@"password"];
```

**2.** Encode the post string using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and also the post string you need to send in NSData format.

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

You need to send the actual length of your data. Calculate the length of the post string.

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
```

**3.** Create a Urlrequest with all the properties like `HTTP` method, http header field with length of the post string. Create `URLRequest` object and initialize it.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
```

Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request.

```
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.abcde.com/xyz/login.aspx"]];
```

Now, set **HTTP** method (*POST or GET*). Write this lines as it is in your code.

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Set `HTTP` header field with length of the post data.

```
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Also set the Encoded value for HTTP header Field.

```
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Set the `HTTPBody` of the urlrequest with postData.

```
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

**4.** Now, create URLConnection object. Initialize it with the URLRequest.

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

It returns the initialized url connection and begins to load the data for the url request. You can check that whether you `URL` connection is done properly or not using just **if/else** statement as below.

```
if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

**5.** To receive the data from the HTTP request , you can use the delegate methods provided by the URLConnection Class Reference.
Delegate methods are as below.

```
// This method is used to receive the data which we get using post method.
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data

// This method receives the error report in case of connection is not made to server. 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 

// This method is used to process the data after connection has made successfully.
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

**Also Refer** [This](http://deusty.blogspot.in/2006/11/sending-http-get-and-post-from-cocoa.html) **and** [This](http://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/nsurlconnection-basics-for-ios-beginners/) **documentation** for `POST` method.

And here is best example with source code of [HTTPPost Method.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315072521/http://kemal.co/index.php/2012/02/fetching-data-with-getpost-methods-by-using-nsurlconnection/)

Comment: Also check if there is no caching going on. That would explain why you got a '200', without anything happening on the server.

Comment: Check the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405151/is-it-possible-to-prevent-an-nsurlrequest-from-caching-data-or-remove-cached-dat and/or google for "nsurlconnection cache policy"

Comment: Thank you so much i checked so much threads and this: http://yuvarajmanickam.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/nsurlconnection-basics-for-ios-beginners/ just worked.

Comment: Even though the answer has been accepted so many times, the given code in this answer has a number of glaring issues, and will be troublesome in practice.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper - I dont know what is ur problem > ? can you explain me ?

Comment: @iPatel But can we send image data using above given post method code.

Comment: As nowadays the popular use case is to send JSON from app to web application, please take note of a few points below: suggest to use NSUTF8StringEncoding for sending and receiving; if the post body is a json, should use [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; instead of @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is incorrect and prone to injection attacks. If the user happens to have an "&" character in the password, all further characters will be parsed as an additional POST parameter. Deliberate manipulation is possible.

Comment: @iPatel can you help me with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573527/calling-web-services-with-the-help-of-afnetworking-in-objective-c

Comment: What if I have to open a Safari rather than UIWebView and need to send Post Parameters to browser?

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)sendingAnHTTPPOSTRequestOniOSWithUserEmailId: (NSString *)emailId withPassword: (NSString *)password{
//Init the NSURLSession with a configuration
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

//Create an URLRequest
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/apis/login_api"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Create POST Params and add it to HTTPBody
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",emailId,password];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

//Create task
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    //Handle your response here
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
     NSLog(@"%@",responseDict);
}];
   [dataTask resume];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure why, but as soon as I comment out the following method it works:

```
connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:
```

Furthermore, I don't think you need the methods from the NSUrlConnectionDownloadDelegate protocol, only those from NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, unless you want some download information.

Comment: I do want the download information that's why i have the function connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:

Comment: Apparently NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate only works in Newsstand apps.... At least that is what this thread says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735121/unable-to-get-destinationurl-data-in-connectiondidfinishdownloading-for-ios5

Answer (score 2):

Heres the method I used in my logging library: https://github.com/goktugyil/QorumLogs

This method fills html forms inside Google Forms. Hope it helps someone using Swift.

```
var url = NSURL(string: urlstring)

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: nil, startImmediately: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C**

> Post API with parameters and validate with url to navigate if json
>   response key with status:"success"

```
NSString *string= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"url?uname=%@&pass=%@&uname_submit=Login",self.txtUsername.text,self.txtPassword.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", str);
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:nil];
    NSDictionary* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", latestLoans];
    NSString *str3=@"success";
    if ([str3 isEqualToString:str2 ])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"move" sender:nil];
        NSLog(@"successfully.");
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertController *alert= [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Try Again"
                                 message:@"Username or Password is Incorrect."
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                       [self.view endEditing:YES];
                                                   }
                             ];
        [alert addAction:ok];
        [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
      }
```

*JSON Response* : {"status":"success","user_id":"58","user_name":"dilip","result":"You have been logged in successfully"} 
    Working code

**

Answer (score 1):

Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS (Objective c):

```
-(NSString *)postexample{

// SEND POST
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL"];
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param=value"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

//RESPONDE DATA 
NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
    NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %li", url, (long)[responseCode statusCode]);
    return nil;
}

//SEE RESPONSE DATA
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Response" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: This is new... Getting replies 4 years after your question is posted :p

Comment: This "postexample" function  is more fast that [Response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15749527/3400859) :p @DaanLuttik

Answer (score 1):

**Using Swift 3 or 4 you can access these http request for sever communication.**

// For POST data to request

```
 func postAction()  {
//declare parameter as a dictionary which contains string as key and value combination. considering inputs are valid
let parameters = ["id": 13, "name": "jack"] as [String : Any]
//create the url with URL
let url = URL(string: "www.requestURL.php")! //change the url
//create the session object
let session = URLSession.shared
//now create the URLRequest object using the url object
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST" //set http method as POST
do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
//create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }
    do {
        //create json object from data
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            print(json)
            // handle json...
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
task.resume() }
```

// For get the data from request

```
func GetRequest()  {
    let urlString = URL(string: "http://www.requestURL.php") //change the url

    if let url = urlString {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
            } else {
                if let responceData = data {
                    print(responceData) //JSONSerialization
                    do {
                        //create json object from data
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:responceData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
                            print(json)
                            // handle json...
                        }
                    } catch let error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

// For get the download content like image or video from request

```
func downloadTask()  {
    // Create destination URL
    let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("downloadedFile.jpg")
    //Create URL to the source file you want to download
    let fileURL = URL(string: "http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1")
    let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
    let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
        if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
            // Success
            if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
            }

            do {
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
            } catch (let writeError) {
                print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription ?? "");
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```