# Send request for signing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsurlrequest

I tried to send request for signing. I have name and password, but I don't know where put it in the code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ec2-54-200-2-249.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/signin"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"Get"];
```

Comment: What does "request for signing" mean? Ah you mean "sign-in"?  You'll need to send an HTTP POST request, not an HTTP GET request.

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-http-post-ios

Comment: @trojanfoe yes it's sign-in. :) But I thought that POST method is for sign-up

Comment: It has no fixed purpose, but within a web page the form data will be sent to the server within a POST request, which allows more data to be sent and the data won't appear in the URL.