# Http Post not getting response from server

Tags: ios, web-services, http-post

I have a web service architecture like this:
Method 
POST method.
URL : https://deluxecms.net/dev/api/index.php

method -  getdocument.

And it takes the following argument

1. method
2. deviceid
3. chiper
4. version
5. lastSync

For cipher, concatenate device id with "11a6b75c30fb0420ed2fccbc9d9cdf80" and encrypt it using md5.
lastSync: Value of Last Response_time from the server.

I am never used web services before,just help me how to get the response message and data from server.

Comment: see my answer [How to use POST method.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-http-post-ios/15749527#15749527)

Comment: md5 is not encryption, it is a hash function. Also "chipper" is not the word you are looking for.

Comment: What is Httpheader feild?

Comment: Take some time and learn about communication with a server via HTTP, it will pay off well. Pasting together a bunch of code that one does not understand is not a viable solution.