# Store the data in web server using HTTP Post methd

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-post

I tried with below code. Here the problem is parameters are directly passing to the database from url.But i need to send the data from Text fields.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:UserProfile.svc/InsertUserDetailsNew?Name=RajeevLeader&FirstName=rajeev&DateofBirth=2012-02-03&Sex=M&Country=India&City=Banglore&PhoneNumber=8523898947&IncumbentonPremimum=true"]];


NSLog(@"url is %@",request);

NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name=%@&FirstName=%@&DateofBirth=%@&Sex=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&PhoneNumber%@&IncumbentonPremimum=%@",name.text, firstname.text,dob.text,gender.text,country.text,city.text,phone.text,premiumtextfield.text];

NSLog(@" RequestString: %@",requestString);

NSMutableData *requestData =[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (con)
{
    NSLog(@"data sent ");
} else
{
    NSLog(@"Not sent");
}

[con start];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending HTTP-Post ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-http-post-ios)

Comment: have u say the correct url, u were passing the url in full value, it is the wrong one,

Comment: if u r given the valid url , I given the answer whatever u  need

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik here is anyway to pass the data from textfields using url

Comment: copy your url, open the new browser and paste ur url,finally u check and tell what the answer u get in browser

Comment: http://192.168.2.4:98/UserProfile.svc/InsertUserDetailsNew?Name=tillu&FirstName=killu&DateofBirth=2012-02-03&Sex=M&Country={Country}&City=ban&PhoneNumber=125875&IncumbentonPremimum=true

if entered this url in browser what ever i mentioned in the url for name: tillu firstname: killu is directly passing into database. but instead of this i need get the data from textfields

Comment: its like a Hotcode @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change your `URL` for the following method

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.4:98/UserProfile.svc/InsertUserDetailsNew"]];



   NSString *requestString = [[NSString alloc]
                  initWithFormat:@"{ \"Name\" : \"%@\" , \"FirstName\" : \"%@\" , \"DateofBirth\" : \"%@\" , \"Sex\" : \"%@\", \"Country\" : \"%@\", \"City\" : \"%@\", \"PhoneNumber\" : \"%@\" , \"FirstName\" : \"%@\"}",
                  name.text, firstname.text,dob.text,gender.text,country.text,city.text,phone.text,premiumtextfield.text];


NSLog(@" RequestString: %@",requestString);

NSMutableData *requestData =[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];




[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];




 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];




 [request setHTTPBody: requestData];
  NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[con start];
```

Comment: in which server u have used .php or java in which server u have used

Comment: webserver[930:a0b] data sent 
webserver[930:a0b] didReceiveResponse: responseData length:(0)
webserver[930:a0b]   parsing JSON: (null)

Comment: http://192.168.2.4:98/UserProfile.svc/InsertUserDetailsNew.?  -- which type of the extension u have used

Comment: extension am not getting http://192.168.2.4:98/UserProfile.svc/InsertUserDetailsNew   i just used it

Comment: if u not get in the response [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; change this line into [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: need more information follow this link http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/connecting-the-iphone-with-aspnet-web-pages

Comment: after the modification also same response :(

Comment: if u not get in the response [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; change this line into [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass parameters afterwords & not with the url.