# Sending Post Request from iOS Simulator to Local Host

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, post

I've been trying to figure this out all morning. I'm sending a POST request from an Objective-C method to a local server on my Mac, using MAMP. When the code runs, the Objective-C method appears to connect successfully, but nothing is received by my PHP script. I rewrote my send method according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios), so it the sending should be correct. I've gone through 10-15 similar questions on SO with no luck. My guess now is that something's wrong with the URL, but I can't find the problem. If someone could help me solve this, that would be great.

Here's my code:

IP address: 10.10.2.143

PHP script address: `http://localhost:8888/hello_world.php`

Objective C:

```
- (void)hasToken:(STPToken *)token
{
    NSLog(@"Received token %@", token.tokenId);

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stripeToken=%@", token.tokenId];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.10.2.143:8888/hello_world.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed...");
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
    echo $_POST;
?>
```

Output:

```
// NSLog
2014-06-16 12:19:45.428 PayPhone Prototype[6519:60b] Received token tok_104EMf4h7nUnb2nUWKejveb9  
2014-06-16 12:19:45.430 PayPhone Prototype[6519:60b] Connection successful!

// PHP
Hello, World!Array
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing a call to the [`start`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/start) method in `NSURLConnection`… just call

`[conn start];`

right after recreating the connection object.

One more thing, the way you are handling the success/fail case does not really make sense, since it only checks that the connection object was created (or not), not that the connection was successful:

```
if (conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection successful!");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed...");
}
```

You should correctly implement your connection object delegate methods:
[`– connectionDidFinishLoading:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connectionDidFinishLoading:)
[`– connection:didReceiveData:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:didReceiveData:)
[`– connection:didFailWithError:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:didFailWithError:) (as it is mentioned in the question you are linking to).

Comment: Thanks, just added the `[conn start]` method in, no luck though. Am I missing something altogether with the PHP? Do I need a `while` loop or something to keep checking if the data has been sent?

Comment: if you implement the delegate's method, especially the `didFailWithError` you can get some more info… also, why don't you try first with a GET (just to troubleshoot things more easily). A GET request is easier to build...

Comment: The data is definitely being sent and received, the problem is with my PHP webpage not refreshing. I asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279215/sending-post-request-to-local-host-data-being-received-but-not-showing-up-on-we