# Sending POST Request to Local Host, Data Being Received But Not Showing Up On Webpage

Tags: php, ios, post

I've been at this for the last couple of days. I'm sending some data from my iPhone app to a localhost on MAMP. The data is definitely being sent to and being received by the server, because the response I'm getting is the PHP code running on the webpage, but it isn't showing up on the webpage. Is there any way to make the webpage display the token being received? I feel that the problem is something really basic with my PHP script. Thanks. Here's the code:

Objective-C:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.12:8888/hello_world.php"]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stripeToken=%@", token.tokenId];

NSLog(body);

request.HTTPBody = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

NSLog:

```
2014-06-18 12:40:12.300 PayPhone Prototype[3775:60b] Received token tok_104F7R4h7nUnb2nUO3XoHPyK
2014-06-18 12:40:12.301 PayPhone Prototype[3775:60b] stripeToken=tok_104F7R4h7nUnb2nUO3XoHPyK
2014-06-18 12:40:12.306 PayPhone Prototype[3775:60b] <html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Hello, World!Array
(
    [stripeToken] => tok_104F7R4h7nUnb2nUO3XoHPyK
)
    </body>
</html>
```

Webpage:

```
Hello, World!Array ( )
```

Comment: how are you getting your "Webpage" output?

Comment: I'm just refreshing the page. Is there any way to make it refresh upon receiving the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your webpage is showing the "wrong" content is because a browser will send a GET request when you visit a URL by writing its URL in the address bar.

Replace your php by this:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello, World!";
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    print_r($_POST);
  } else {
    echo "This was not a POST";
  }
?>
```

And you will see it.

In order for you to have your browser send a post, you should, e.g., create a form that will do a POST to your php page; or you could do that in JavaScript (similarly to what you are doing from Objective-C). I doubt it would be useful.

So, it seems that your app is working and your php page is behaving correctly.

Possibly you should explain what you are trying to do by loading the php page in your browser -- if it is just for testing, then you do not need it. The `NSLog` you added already tells you all.

Comment: Apparently the PHP script runs only once and can't update the page dynamically, so what I'm trying to do here isn't possible. But the log is enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store the array in a variable like below

```
<?php 
$variable = array
 (
"stripeToken" => "tok_104F7R4h7nUnb2nUO3XoHPyK"
 );
?>
```

then echo on webpage

```
 hello, word <?php echo $variable['stripeToken']; ?>
```