# Post video to server without multipart

Tags: objective-c, json

Iam trying to POST a video either recorded or chosen from the Library to server. This is the code I use to get video in the form of NSData

```
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```

Now , I need to encode it using base64 and POST. But when I POST, the server receives no video. Any guidance would be great. Thankyou

Comment: can you show the code where you are posting the video ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Also, base64 related methods are included in iOS7. If your deploy target is below iOS 7, try [this](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

Here's [Post Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)

Comment: Problem is not in posting. Problem is, that Iam not able to post 'video' specifically.