# IOS8 Parameter is not getting appended to URL when posting data

Tags: ios, web-services, rest

I am calling the REST service to post lat & lng, however The data is not getting send to server

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    self.locationDesc.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",crnLoc.description];
    NSLog(@"%@",crnLoc.description);
    NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/web/location/create.php?"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:aUrl];
    NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"latitude=%g&longitude=%g", crnLoc.coordinate.latitude, crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   NSLog(@"%@",request.URL);
}
```

**Is something wrong here which I am doing in above code?** I can post the data using REST Easy client (firefox add-ons).

Comment: what are the parameters and where are you appending here?

Comment: >> The parameters are @"latitude=%g&longitude=%g", .... at * param and sending at [request setHTTPBody:[params.....

Comment: I wanted to pass the lat & lng to webservice so that the final url is - http://localhost/web/location/create.php?latitude=1111&longitude=22222 but somehow url is not getting constructed

Comment: If you want them in the URL you need to add them to the location. Right now you are putting them in the body. Or if it indeed a post request, the data should be put in the body and the service should get the data from the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
CLLocation *crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
self.locationDesc.text = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",crnLoc.description];
NSLog(@"%@",crnLoc.description);
NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/web/location/create.php?"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                            requestWithURL:aUrl];
NSString *params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"latitude=%g&longitude=%g", crnLoc.coordinate.latitude, crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
NSData *postData = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(con) 
{
   NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} 
else 
{
   NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

For reference:

[Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)

Comment: Thanks for update but data is not getting sent to server. The parameter are still not appended to url. I printed the [param] and request.url  'NSLog(@"%@",params);'  prints - latitude=-33.8634&longitude=151.211 and request.url - http://localhost/web/location/create.php?.

Comment: The problem is http://localhost/web/location/create.php? because it gives Unable to connect.So give the correct URL.Otherwise it won't append.

Comment: Above if my answer is helpful for you,please tick and give me the mark.

Comment: No its connecting and i am getting "Connection Successful" Will defiantly give the mark.

Comment: It turns out to the url parameter instead of sending the body:) finally I have to do the following to test the webservice using simulator.   NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/web/location/create.php?latitude=222&longitude=111"];