# How to pass JSON parameters to IOS SDK for AWS API gateway?

Tags: ios, json, api, amazon-web-services

Using AWS API Gateway console, I've generated an IOS SDK for my API. And here is the code I get in the `APIClient.m` generated

```
    (AWSTask *)getpositionsPost {

       NSDictionary *headerParameters = @{
       @"Content-Type": @"application/json",
       @"Accept": @"application/json",

   };
       NSDictionary *queryParameters = @{

  };
     NSDictionary *pathParameters = @{

 };

       return [self invokeHTTPRequest:@"POST"
       URLString:@"/getpositions"
       pathParameters:pathParameters
       queryParameters:queryParameters
       headerParameters:headerParameters
       body:nil
       responseClass:APIEmpty class];
     }
```

How do I call this method and pass it a JSON parameter to send parameters to API ? The code to call the API is

```
APIClient *client = APIClient defaultClient;
[client getpositionsPost continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
if (task.error) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
       return nil;
}
if (task.result) {
       APIEmpty * output = task.result;
       NSLog(@"Result: %@", task.result);
       //Do something with output
   }
  return nil;
}];
```

But I don't know how to pass it a POST JSON Paramater as requested by my API ?
This question is not a duplicate of [Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486) as AWS encapsulates its own http classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)

Comment: hi, not really as aws encapsulates its own http class so you can't use the method proposed in this answer

Comment: You don't know how to pass a parameter?

Comment: in this case no... i don't understand how the method is working

Comment: Hint: what do you think that the function of the `body` parameter is?

Comment: Tip: your resource should be called "position" with GET and POST methods...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the generated SDK, your API is not defined to take an input object. You should follow [Amazon API Gateway Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html) and set up Models and Mapping Templates.