# Sending an HTTP POST request and Receive a responce from server on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection

I am trying to get connection from server and receive response from server but I can't understand for the response code.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Username=%@&Password=%@",@"_username",@"_password"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://<MY_URL>"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

**this is correct or not because I am not getting a response .??**

**now what is code for response?????**

```
NSURLResponse *response=nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
if (response) {
  //UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
  //TableViewController *obj=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"table1"];
  UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login success" message:@"correct Username or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil];
  [alert show];
  //[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
else
{
  UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Login Failure" message:@"Incorrect Username or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles: nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `NSLog` ?

Comment: Connection Successful

Comment: I meaned this one `NSLog(@"%@",response);`

Comment: this output is (null)

Comment: Could you use an NSError when you send the request ? Declare `NSError * requestError = nil` before the request, pass it as error parameter `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError ];` and finally use `NSLog` it inside the last `else` statement. What is the result of this log?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALL the code is correct only you need to add the this in your info.plist

> App Transport Security Setting
>
> - Allow arbitrary Loads

[image: add red box content in your info.plist]

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch that data:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(responseData)  { 
    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments  error:&error];
    NSLog(@"res---%@", results);
}
```

and use dictionary for further use.

Comment: **NSlog(@"%@",responseData1);** is null

Comment: any error is there means can u plz check the NSError is nil or what?

Comment: no error but when i check the responseData1 output that is null

Comment: OK let me do it by myself once

Comment: i am getting error like below
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “joomerang.geniusport.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Comment: You are using https, but the website only seems to work on http. So either you need to fix your certificates or use the site via HTTP

Comment: but i have the user name and password to login this server

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS has nothing to do with passwords and logins. HTTPS just means your communication with that site is encrypted.

Comment: Please don't recommend sendSynchronousRequest:.  It is dangerous to use that method on the main thread, and if you use it on any other thread, it leaks.