# REST Web API POST calling gives an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to send POST request to a web service from my iOS app. So far, I have sent a JSON object and it is working. Now I want to send data as parameters. I did something like this.

```
[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[postParam UTF8String] length:[postParam length]]];
 NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error: &error];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This is my `postParam` string

```
action=approve&requestId=0&reqDetailId=21&nextApproverCode=0&authIpAddress=122.127.0.114&remarks=Test&approval=C
```

This is my `request`

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x151323e60> { URL: http://<url>/Workflows/WorkflowApprovals? }
```

But I'm getting an error message

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://<url>/Workflows/WorkflowApprovals'."}
```

What is the reason for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As it is a POST method you can't send in query string

Create one dictionary and and pass all the parameter in it

Comment: But check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios he has done it using query string

Comment: you can pass but its better not to pass in URL for POST type