# Send http requests when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, http

I have a function which is sending an HTTP request once in 60 sec, but when I lock phone it stops. So, is there a way to send HTTP requests when a phone is locked?
I've tried to do it in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

but it's not worked.

Comment: Also maybe this is able to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code seems right to me...
It should work as long as the code that you add it in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` function of your AppDelegate. If the device is locked shouldn't matter from what I've seen. It's still able to perform tasks if the device is locked (ie. play audio)

Also make sure that if you are doing anything in the background that the app has the ability to make Background refreshes, if need be. You can add that in your Capabilities tab under the main project file in Xcode. I think that might be where your issue stems from.