# For Ios how to send image or video to server with keys in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios.
   How to send an image or an video to php server. i have a key **"Image"**
for **sending image**  and key **"Video"** to send video file. i need to send image or video with their keys, how can i send...?

Comment: have a look on [AFNEtworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)!!

Comment: yes but how to import AFNEtworking..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an HTTP POST request on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Post` method. And you should archive image/video to data and make sheet data to send it to server.
I suggest you use Alamofire to do this. This is the code.

```
let imageData = UIPNGRepresentation(image)!

Alamofire.upload(imageData, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Here is [the link.](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

**Update**

As you're familiar with OC, use AFNetworking instead. This is the code.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://example.com/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.jpg"] name:@"file" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg" error:nil];
    } error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager
              uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
              progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
                  // This is not called back on the main queue.
                  // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      //Update the progress view
                      [progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
                  });
              }
              completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                  } else {
                      NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
                  }
              }];

[uploadTask resume];
```

Here is [the link.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)