# IOS/Objective-C: String length Syntax for HTTP Post to Server

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

For a JSON request to a server, I am using some code that includes a value for the length of a string as follows:

```
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

This code, however, is throwing a warning that `%d` should not be used for the length and the code be changed to `%lu(unsigned long)`.

I am following the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749486/sending-an-http-post-request-on-ios/15750084) and numerous other places that says:

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
```

Should I follow Xcode's suggestion?  I am a bit reluctant to change working code as I have found XCode's suggestions to occasionally cause unintended problems.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: It's related to 32 vs 64 bits. Nowadays, with all iDevices supported by current XCode version being 64 bits, you'll get the warning. Note, that you can use a little trick: `@"%@", @(postData length)]`

Comment: I used your trick and it got rid of warning